# tax_query with custom taxonomy not working as expected

Tags: wordpress

I'm hoping someone can help spot what the problem is. I have a custom taxonomy called "events_cat" I am trying to get all the post types "event" that are in the taxonomy term 11 to display, however the below code is pulling in events that are not in that taxonomy term and I can't see the mistake. Any ideas what might be causing the issue?:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
            'post_type'        => 'event',
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'tax_query'        => array(
                                   'relation' => 'AND',
                                   array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'events_cat',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => array(11),
                                    ),
            ));
    $upcomingEvents = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$custom_args=array(
              'post_type'   => "event",
              'post_status'     => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
              'caller_get_posts'=> -1,
              'hierarchical'    => 1,
              'exclude'         => '',
              'include'         => '',
              'number'          => '',
              'tax_query'       => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'events_cat',
                                            'field' => 'id',
                                            'terms' =>"11"
                                        )
                                    ),
             'orderby'          => 'id',
             'order'            => 'ASC'
            );
            $custom_my_query = null;
            $custom_my_query = new WP_Query($custom_args);
            $custom_my_total_count = count($custom_my_query);
            if( $custom_my_query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                    while ($custom_my_query->have_posts()) : $custom_my_query->the_post(); 
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?></a>
                        <?php
                      endwhile;
            }
            wp_reset_query($custom_my_query);  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It should work but it didn't sort the issue. I have now discovered that there was a function in the template's function.php file that was overriding the query which was why it wasn't working as expected.

Comment: But what is your taxonomy slug? please share your full code.